# ring: convert a ring back to a list -- keeping rotation

Tags: list, rings

In the following example, the element `(c fig)` is the `current-item`.  The user has chosen to rotate the ring forwards, by calling `ring-next`.  How can a user return the revised list in its rotated state; i.e., with `(d banana)` at the front?

```lisp
(progn
  (require 'ring)
  (let* ((the-list '((a apple)
                     (b pear)
                     (c fig)
                     (d banana)
                     (e orange)))
         (current-item '(c fig))
         (ring-seq (ring-convert-sequence-to-ring the-list))
         (previous-item (ring-previous ring-seq current-item))
         (next-item (ring-next ring-seq current-item)))
   next-item))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can answer this type of question simply by reading the source in ring.el. The whole file is shorter and simpler than you might be expecting.

`ring-next` doesn’t rotate the ring at all, it simply searches the ring to find the index where `current-item` is found in the ring, adds one to that index, and fetches whatever is at that index in the ring (modulo the ring length). `ring-previous` does exactly the same thing. You simply want to get the current index, add one to it (modulo the ring length), and set the index to that new value, then return the ring:

```lisp
(setf (car ring)
      (ring-plus1 (ring-member ring current-item)
                  (ring-length ring)))
```

Once you have modified the current index of the ring, you can call `ring-elements` to convert it back to a list in the desired order.

Comment: Thank you ... Inasmuch as the ring is not a list per se, how do we convert the modified ring back into a list with `(d banana)` at the front?  E.g., the modified ring (using the snippet in the answer above) looks like:  `(3 5 . [(e orange) (d banana) (c fig) (b pear) (a apple)])`

Comment: Thank you for the update.  Using `ring-elements` with the snippet in the answer above, the return value is:  `((c fig) (d banana) (e orange) (a apple) (b pear))`  -- ie., `(d banana)` is not at the front of the list.

Comment: Then use `next-item` or whichever element you prefer in place of `current-item`. Incidentally, `next-item` is `(b pear)` rather than `(d banana)`, which is actually in `previous-item`.

Comment: Thank you ... Based upon some testing using different items as the current item, from which to determine next/previous items, it appears that `ring-plus1` and `ring-minus1` cannot reliably be used to mathematically calculate the desired `(car ring)`.  I wrote up an alternative answer using a loop to examine all possible list variations.  If you are able to write-up a solution that mathematically determines the appropriate `(car ring)` based upon any item in the ring as the current item, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

**USAGE**:

```lisp
(progn
  (require 'ring)
  (let* ((the-list '((a apple)
                     (b pear)
                     (c fig)
                     (d banana)
                     (e orange)))
         (item '(d banana))
         (ring (ring-convert-sequence-to-ring the-list)))
    (message "\nPREVIOUS:  %s\n" (ring-convert-ring-to-sequence ring item 'previous))
    (message "CURRENT:  %s\n" (ring-convert-ring-to-sequence ring item 'current))
    (message "NEXT:  %s\n" (ring-convert-ring-to-sequence ring item 'next))
    nil))
```

**RESULT**:  Displayed in the `*Messages*` buffer.

```
PREVIOUS:  ((c fig) (d banana) (e orange) (a apple) (b pear))

CURRENT:  ((d banana) (e orange) (a apple) (b pear) (c fig))

NEXT:  ((e orange) (a apple) (b pear) (c fig) (d banana))
```

**THE CODE**:

```
(defun ring-convert-ring-to-sequence (ring item position)
  "The RING can be created by using `ring-convert-sequence-to-ring'.
ITEM should be an element of the sequence used to create the RING.
POSITION must be a symbol in the form of: 'current | 'next | 'previous
Return the rotated sequence.  Reset the ring to its original state when done."
  (let* ((initial-setting (car ring))
         (ring-length (ring-length ring))
         (vec (make-vector ring-length nil))
         previous current next)
    (dotimes (i ring-length)
      (aset vec i i))
    (mapc (lambda (idx)
            (setf (car ring) idx)
            (let ((new-list (ring-elements ring)))
              (cond ((equal item (car new-list))
                       (setq current new-list))
                    ((equal item (car (last new-list)))
                       (setq next new-list))
                    ((equal item (nth 1 new-list))
                       (setq previous new-list)))))
          vec)
    (setf (car ring) initial-setting)
    (cond ((eq 'current position)
             current)
          ((eq 'next position)
             next)
          ((eq 'previous position)
             previous))))
```

Comment: I don’t know what problem you’re trying to fix, but this code is really bad. First, it calls `ring-elements` once for each element in the ring, meaning it conses O(n²) times and then throws all of that work away. Second, it loops over the numbers from 0 to `ring-length` putting the numbers in the vector, then immediately loops over the vector. This type of double loop is a waste of time. Finally, it also sets the global variables `current`, `next`, and `previous`.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem I am trying to solve is to obtain a reliable method to return:  CURRENT, NEXT and PREVIOUS in the form of a list that is extracted from the RING using a reference point of a particular ITEM in the ring.  In this example, I used the ITEM `(d banana)` to obtain the lists for CURRENT, NEXT and PREVIOUS.  I tried to use the ITEM `(d banana)` every which way with the code from your answer, but the `(car ring)` is not being set properly as far as I can tell.  Perhaps you could provide an example, using your code, of how to obtain the same results in my answer using `(d banana)`.